# Mirror bargraphs with labels on each side for dichotomous variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a mirror bargraph that displays dichotomous variables using ggplot2. Basically, what I'm trying to do would look something like this:

[image]

I tried arranging the data like this and then running the code below to create a stacked horizontal bargraph:

```
value  trait        position
30     Analytical    left
92     Creative      right
49     Learning      left
70     Analytical    right
8      Creative      left
51     Learning      right
```

```
#simulated data
trait <- c(rep("Creative" , 2) , rep("Analytical" , 2) , rep("Learning" , 2))
position <- rep(c("right" , "left") , 2)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(value,trait,position)

p1<- ggplot(data, aes(x=trait, y=value, fill="position")) +
    geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", alpha=.6, width=.4) +
  scale_fill_brewer()+
  labs(title="Percentiles")+
  geom_text(aes(label=value, hjust = 1))+
    coord_flip() +
    xlab("") +
    theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position="none",axis.text=element_text(size=12, face="bold"), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank(), panel.borde=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank())
```

The problem I have is that, although the bars stack, the labels indicating the value of each stacked bar are all around the place, as you can see in the picture. Additionally, how do I add labels to both the right and the left of the bargraphs, like in the example I linked above? Because even if my code worked fine, there would only be labels to the left.

[image]

The original dataset looks like this:

```
value   trait         value2     trait2
30      Analytical     70        Improvise
92      Creative        8        Operational
49      Learning       51        Action
```

Thanks if anyone can help, I feel like I tried everything here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>%
  group_by(trait, position) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  mutate(value = prop.table(value) * 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=trait, y=value, fill=position)) +
  geom_col() + 
  labs(title="Percentiles")+
  geom_text(aes(label= paste0(round(value, 2), '%')), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.text=element_text(size=12, face="bold"), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        panel.borde=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess I felt like having a challenge so I tried to replicate that chart as best I could. There a couple of extra things I had to do in order to achieve this. The first is to use the `ggtext` package to better control the look of the text above the charts. Note the HTML formatting in the data to achieve this.

The second is to use `geom_segment()` instead of `geom_bar()`/`geom_col()` to come up with the pill shape of the bars. Specifically, I set 3 layers of `geom_segment()`, which in order, set the part of the chart on the right, set the part of the chart on the left (but ending a bit short, here deducting -1, to avoid the rounding to show), and a third part to cap the bar so that it has the vertical break between the two categories.

You could obviously fiddle around more with the fonts and text sizes, but I think it does the job fairly well.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

# Setting up data    
mydf <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ title, ~ label, ~ perc, ~ position, ~ colour, ~ colour_label,
  "<span style='font-size:18pt'>**MIND**</span><br><span style='color:#A5A5A5;font-size:14pt'>This trait determines how we interact with our environment", "EXTRAVERTED", .6, "left", "#5BAAAC", "white",
  "<span style='font-size:18pt'>**MIND**</span><br><span style='color:#A5A5A5;font-size:14pt'>This trait determines how we interact with our environment", "INTROVERTED", .4, "right", "#F5F5F5", "#4A4A4A",
  "<span style='font-size:18pt'>**ENERGY**</span><br><span style='color:#A5A5A5;font-size:14pt'>This trait shows where we direct our mental energy", "INTUITIVE", .7, "left",  "#5BAAAC", "white",
  "<span style='font-size:18pt'>**ENERGY**</span><br><span style='color:#A5A5A5;font-size:14pt'>This trait shows where we direct our mental energy", "OBSERVANT", .3, "right", "#F5F5F5", "#4A4A4A",
  "<span style='font-size:18pt'>**NATURE**</span><br><span style='color:#A5A5A5;font-size:14pt'>This trait determines how we make decisions and cope with emotions", "THINKING", .65, "left", "#5BAAAC", "white",
  "<span style='font-size:18pt'>**NATURE**</span><br><span style='color:#A5A5A5;font-size:14pt'>This trait determines how we make decisions and cope with emotions", "FEELING", .35, "right", "#F5F5F5", "#4A4A4A",
  "<span style='font-size:18pt'>**TACTICS**</span><br><span style='color:#A5A5A5;font-size:14pt'>This trait reflects our approach to work, planning and decision-making", "JUDGING", .31, "left", "#F5F5F5", "#4A4A4A",
  "<span style='font-size:18pt'>**TACTICS**</span><br><span style='color:#A5A5A5;font-size:14pt'>This trait reflects our approach to work, planning and decision-making", "PROSPECTING", .69, "right", "#5BAAAC", "white",
  "<span style='font-size:18pt'>**IDENTITY**</span><br><span style='color:#A5A5A5;font-size:14pt'>This trait underpins all others, showing how confident we are in our abilities and decisions", "ASSERTIVE", .69, "left", "#5BAAAC", "white",
  "<span style='font-size:18pt'>**IDENTITY**</span><br><span style='color:#A5A5A5;font-size:14pt'>This trait underpins all others, showing how confident we are in our abilities and decisions", "TURBULENT", .31, "right", "#F5F5F5", "#4A4A4A"
)

mydf$title <- forcats::fct_inorder(mydf$title)

ggplot(mydf) + 
  geom_segment(data = dplyr::filter(mydf, position == "right"), aes(x = 1, y = 0, yend = 1, xend = 1, colour = colour), size = 25, lineend = "round") +
  geom_segment(data = dplyr::filter(mydf, position == "left"), aes(x = 1, y = 0, yend = perc - 0.1, xend = 1, colour = colour), size = 25, lineend = "round") +
  geom_segment(data = dplyr::filter(mydf, position == "left"), aes(x = 1, y = .1, yend = perc, xend = 1, colour = colour), size = 25) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 1, y = ifelse(position == "left", 0.005, 0.995)), shape = "circle", colour = "white", size = 22) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(perc, accuracy = 1), x = 1, y = ifelse(position == "left", 0.005, 0.995)), size = 7, fontface = "bold") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label, x = 1, y = ifelse(position == "left", 0.05, 0.95), hjust = ifelse(position == "left", 0, 1), colour = colour_label), size = 7, fontface = "bold") +
  geom_richtext(aes(label = title, x = 1.007, y = 0.5), label.size = NA) +
  xlim(c(0.99, 1.01)) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(vars(title), ncol = 1) +
  scale_colour_identity() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]